# Change highlighted color back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with changed color back when I move to another tab. As you can see here: http://lordmonarch.net84.net/ when you press on any tab in contacts it changes colour, but when you move to another it is not changing its colour back. Here is my code:

```
$('.contfield').click(function(){
            if ($('.contclickedinfo').is(':hidden')) {
                $('.contclickedinfo').show();
                $(this).css("background-color","rgb(23,55,94)");
                $(this).css("color","#FFF");    
            }
            else{
                $('.contclickedinfo').hide();
                $(this).css("background-color","rgb(217,217,217)");
                $(this).css("color","#383838");
            }
            return false;
        });

        $('.contclickedinfo').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(document).click(function() {
            $('.contclickedinfo').hide();
            $(this).css("background-color","rgb(217,217,217)");
            $(this).css("color","#383838");
        });
```

And html:

```
<div class="contacts">
            <div class="conthead">
                Contacts
            </div>
            <div class="confields">
                <div class="contfield">
                    Jim Granger - CEO
                </div>
                <div class="contfield">
                    Frank Grant - CFO
                </div>
                <div class="contfield">
                    Dolly Marsden – SVP BD
                </div>
                <div class="contfield">
                    Angus Lewis – SVP Marketing
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contclickedinfo">
                <div class="contbox">
                    <table border="0">
                         <tr>
                         <td>Phone</td>
                         <td><div class="contrightfield">+82 9999 9999</div></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                         <td>Email</td>
                         <td><div class="contrightfield">jim.granger@abccmo.com</div></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                         <td>Address</td>
                         <td><div class="contrightfield">12 First Road,
                            Kowloon,
                            Hong Kong
                            X123 Y456</div>
                         </td>
                         </tr>
                         </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The website you linked to is unreachable as your host says 'you are checking for malicious content'

Comment: Just a tip, instead of hardcoding the color values, i would add/remove classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if ($('.contclickedinfo').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.contfield').css("background-color","rgb(217,217,217)");
        $('.contfield').css("color","#383838");
        $('.contclickedinfo').show();
        $(this).css("background-color","rgb(23,55,94)");
        $(this).css("color","#FFF");    
    }
```